# If a state space realization $(A,B,C, D)$ is minimal, will its inverse also be minimal?

Tags: matrices, control-theory, linear-control

How to prove that (and why is it that) if a state space realization (A,B,C, D) is a minimal realization, then $(A^{-1},B^{-1},C^{-1},D^{-1})$ will also be a minimal realization?

One way to define a minimal realization would be:

[image]

I should also add that for the above proof, we know that a state space realization $(\hat{A}, \hat{B}, \hat{C}, \hat{D})$ of the inverse transfer function is given by: 
$$
\begin{align}
\hat{A} &= A-B\,D^{-1}C\\
\hat{B} &= B\,D^{-1}\\
\hat{C} &= -D^{-1}C\\
\hat{D} &= D^{-1}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: How is minimal realization defined? You should give more details. Most of the people on this site are mathematicians. And the probability is quite high that they never came in touch with control theory.

Comment: What do you mean by the inverse? Because normally you can only calculate the inverse of a matrix if it is square and non-singular. Or are you referring to the state space model whose corresponding transfer function is the inverse of the transfer function of the original state space model?

Answer (score 1):

The "inverse" realization as you have defined it need not even exist for some minimal realizations.

For example, if $H(s)$ is any proper rational transfer function (MIMO or SISO--it doesn't matter) then it has a minimal realization with $D = 0$. In this case $D^{-1}$ does not exist and as a result all of the $A^{-1}, B^{-1}, C^{-1}$ as you have put them are not defined.

Furthermore, since $D$ is $\dim Y \times \dim U$ it isn't square in general, so it doesn't even make sense to talk about a matrix inverse of $D$.

Answer (score 0):

For SISO systems the answer is yes, since the state space representation model is minimal, the corresponding transfer function is also minimal. Inverse of the minimal transfer function would still be minimal because otherwise the noninverted transfer function would not be minimal.

However, if $D=0$ then the inverse is not causal and the state representation is not well-defined but only makes sense as a descriptor system or a transfer function with a numerator polynomial having higher degree than the numerator.